# <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> invalid table/column name "size" is a "ALL" reserved SQL/NOSQL keyword

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py, web2py-modules

```
      db.define_table('bookspace',
            Field('locaton','string'),
            Field('size','string'),
            Field('availablefrom', 'string'),
            Field('availableto', 'string'),
            Field('rooftype', 'string'),
            Field('sitetype', 'string'),
            Field('name', 'string'),
            Field('email', 'string'),
            Field('mobile', 'string'),
            Field('industry_food', 'string'),
            Field('industry_ecommerce', 'string'),
            Field('industry_furniture', 'string'),
            Field('industry_exim', 'string'),
            Field('industry_auto', 'string'),
            Field('industry_chemical', 'string'),
            Field('industry_logistics', 'string'),
            Field('industry_construction', 'string'),
            Field('industry_agriculture', 'string'),
            Field('industry_telecom', 'string'),
            Field('industry_others', 'string'),
            Field('parameter_rent','string'),
            Field('parameter_numgates', 'string'),
            Field('parameter_numdocks', 'string'),
            Field('parameter_centralheight', 'string'),
            Field('parameter_sidewallheight', 'string'),
            Field('parameter_parkingarea', 'string'),
            Field('parameter_firenoc', 'string'),
            Field('parameter_foodlicense', 'string'),
            Field('service_transportation','string'),
            Field('service_security', 'string'),
            Field('service_cctv', 'string'),
            Field('service_insurance', 'string'),
            Field('service_racking', 'string'),
            Field('service_pallets', 'string'),
            Field('service_forklift', 'string'),
            Field('service_powerbackup', 'string'),
            Field('service_loading', 'string'),
            format='%(name)s')
```

By typing the above code i am getting this error( invalid table/column name "size" is a "ALL" reserved SQL/NOSQL keyword)Help me get rid out of this.
what should be used in this case.
thks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size is a word that is reserved by the db. That is, they have a special meaning to the db and so cannot be redefined. For this reason, you cannot use them to name database objects such as columns, tables, or indexes.  Try using a different name instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set appropriate value for `check_reserved` in DAL signature.

Read this - [Reserved keywords](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Reserved-keywords)

Other solution can be, use `rname` to give other name for field. This new name will be used in db but you can use 'size' in your code.

Read [Field constructor-rname](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

```
db = DAL(..., entity_quoting=True)
```

http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Database-quoting-and-case-settings-entity_quoting-ignore_field

Comment: This must be quote all table fields and in output sql instead of `size varchar(10)` will `"size" varchar(10)`